# Does it matter what you call after() method with?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following piece of code (using Tkinter) that increases the value of a counter by 1 every second:

```
import tkinter as tk

def count():
    global counter
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    counter += 1
    label.after(1000, count)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

counter = 0 
count()

root.mainloop()
```

It works just the same if I change:

```
label.after(1000, count)
```

to:

```
root.after(1000, count)
```

Does it matter what you call `after()` with? If so, in what situations would it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not matter.  `after` is a basic widget method that is available on *all* widgets.  In fact, `Label.after` and `Tk.after` are the exact same function object:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.Label.after is tkinter.Tk.after
True
>>>
```

For a complete list of the methods that are shared among all Tkinter widgets, see [Basic Widget Methods](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to have windows owned by different threads in Tkinter? If so, then the difference would likely be that it executes on the thread that owns the widget you called it on.

Comment: Within the same thread though, it makes no difference whether you call it on one widget or another.  My answer was showing that `after` is not sensitive to the widget object's type, as the OP believed.